# Change color of Angular material expansion header on hover

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material 7 Expansion Panel. When I hover over one of the **mat-expansion-panel-header** the color is changing. How can I change this color?

Code:

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
              Titel
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>Hi</mat-panel-description>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          Content
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: mat-expansion-panel-header the color is changing?? can you be very specific how the color is changing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a class to the header and set background color to currentColor on hover something like

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel>
          <mat-expansion-panel-header class="disable_ripple">
            <mat-panel-title>
              Titel
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>Hi</mat-panel-description>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          Content
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

then in css

```
.disable_ripple:hover{
background: currentColor !important;
}
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwufrk)

Answer (score 11):

Add this to your component CSS file

```
mat-expansion-panel-header:hover {
    background-color: currentColor
}
```